# Imported variable is able to use its origin-module's function, how?

Tags: javascript

module1.js:

```
function increment(n){
    return ++n; 
   }
   
   let a = {
    b: increment(1),
   }
   
   export {a};
```

module2.js:

```
import {a} from "./module1.js"

console.log(a); // prints 2.
```

Why is this not problematic? I exported only `a` but somehow it was able to use the function increment while being inside module2.js which doesn't even have the increment function. Could someone explain how this works exactly?

Edit: I know this doesn't need the module pattern. This was just an oversimplified example to show the question I had in my mind.

Comment: "*Why is this not problematic?*" because that's literally how all closures work. Moreover, if it *didn't* have access to `increment`, then all of importing would be useless - you'd only export so simple that they don't have dependencies. And you probably don't really need them modularised in the first place.

Comment: Also... all import functionality I know of will maintain the relations and ability to access stuff that's *not* imported. Java, C#, Python, for example. You can only import one thing and you don't need its dependencies.

Comment: The entire module script is loaded, when you import modules. The imported modules are closed in a namespace, and as VLAZ has stated, everything else in the module script is accessible via a closure. It's not problematic, when you know it, but I've to admit, that when I learnt to use modules, it was a surprise to me, that all the script was loaded. The goal was to create a compact authorization system with modules, I had to redesign the entire system when I saw the entire script was loaded, not just the imported parts.